# Drawing millions of segments on screen

Tags: graphics, xna

I would like to draw millions of line segments to the screen.
Most of the time user will see only certain area of "universe", but the user should have the ability to "zoom" out to see all line segments at once.

My understanding is that the primitive is a "triangle", so I will have to express my line segments as triangles. Millions of triangles.

Is XNA the right tool for this job, or will it be too slow?

Additional Detail:

1. This is not for a game, but for a modeling program of some processes.
2. I do not care which language to use (XNA was recommended to me)

P.S.: Please let me know if you need additional detail.

Comment: Why would you like to draw so many lines? Is it for a game?

Comment: Do you have a specific language you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that the primitive
>   is a "triangle", so I will have to
>   express my line segments as triangles.
>   Millions of triangles.

Incorrect, XNA can perfectly draw lines for you in the following manner:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, vertexOffset, 0, numVertices, startIndex, primitiveCount);
```

(Or PrimitiveType.LineStrip if the end vertex of line1 is the start vertex of line2).

> Is XNA the right tool for this job, or
>   will it be too slow?

XNA is "a tool", and if you're drawing a lot of lines this is definately going to be faster than GDI+ and easy to implement than C++ in combo with Unmannaged D3D. Drawing a line is a very cheap operation. I would advice you to just install XNA and do a quick prototype to see how many lines you can draw at the same time. (My guess is at least 1 million). Then see if you really need to use the advanced techniques described by the other posters.

Also the "Polyline simplification" technique suggested by Felice Pollano doesn't work for individual lines, only for models made up of triangles (you can exchange a lot of small triangles for a few bigger once to increase performance but decrease visuals, if you're zoomed out pritty far nobody will notice) It also won't work for "thickened up lines" because they will always consist of 2 triangles. (Unless if you allow bended lines).

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom into details simple bounding box check if the triangle is visible to avoid drawing invisible objects. When user zoom all, you should apply some algorithm of polyline simplification http://www.softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0205/algorithm_0205.htm to avoid have too many things to draw.

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xnagamestudioexpress/thread/acfd8361-81ac-4c87-9d2d-93022a8789b7) had your same problem, and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manders/archive/2007/01/07/lines-2d-thick-rounded-line-segments-for-xna-programs.aspx) might help ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-01-42-82-07/LinesDemo_5F00_1_5F00_0.zip) are the sources).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Felice alludes to, simplifying the problem-set is the name of the game. There are obvious limits to hardware and algorithms, so the only way to draw "more stuff" is actually to draw "less stuff".

You can use techniques such as dividing your scene into an [OctTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) so that you can do [View Frustrum Culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_frustum_culling). There are tons of techniques for scaling out what you're drawing. One of my favorites is the use of impostors to create a composite scene which is easier to draw. Here's a paper which explains the technique:
http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/1241430.aspx

> Impostors are **image-based primitives**
>   commonly used to **replace complex**
>   **geometry** in order to reduce the
>   rendering time needed for displaying
>   complex scenes. However, a big problem
>   is the huge amount of memory required
>   for impostors. This paper presents an
>   algorithm that automatically places
>   impostors into a scene so that a
>   desired frame rate image quality is
>   always met, while at the same time not
>   requiring enormous amounts of impostor
>   memory. The low memory requirements
>   are provided by a new placement method
>   and through the simultaneous use of
>   other acceleration techniques like
>   **visibility culling** and **geometric
>   levels of detail**.

Comment: Both you and Felice jump on algorithms and techniques that just don't make any sense for line fragments :). You need double the amount of vertices for an imposter image as for a line.